# openacc nested loops with dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, openacc

I am trying to apply openacc to develop multicore and gpu accelerated binaries.  I have read the Farber book and successfully ran test programs from there and through some on-line courses offered by NVIDIA.  Then, I attempted to parallelize on our legacy code.

The subroutine I am writing has a dependency on a three-dimensional array which is used within three nested loops.  This is a typical N(N+1)/2 pair wise distance problem for a trajectory of nsteps.  For our science problem, nsteps is typically 1E5 to 1E7, nparticles is 1E4 to 5E5.

```
for(i=0 ; i < nsteps ; i++){
    pair = 0 ;
    for(j=0 ; j < nparticles-1 ; j++){
        x1 = position[i][j][0] ;
        y1 = position[i][j][1] ;
        z1 = position[i][j][2] ;
        for(k=j+1 ; k < nparticles ; k++){
            x2 = position[i][k][0] ;
            y2 = position[i][k][1] ;
            z2 = position[i][k][2] ;
            dx2 = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) ;
            dy2 = (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) ;
            dz2 = (z1 - z2) * (z1 - z2) ;
            sdist = sqrt(dx2 + dy2 + dz2) ;
            dist[pair] += sdist ;
            pair++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no control of the input position array (nsteps, nparticles) at compile time as the code is run through python to a C++ extension that converts the python numpy array to a C-array data type.  The openacc code is to be compiled as a source object library.  The C++ extension calls the openacc code.  This is a legacy code that requires this arrangement.  The steps to define the system in Python, call the C++ extension and access the openacc *.so file works fine.

The issue is that this problem is not readily obvious in the book or the exercises from the course and therefore the solution and/or comments on the problem may help others.

I have tried the parallel, kernels and loop & data directives on the code snippet shown using some examples on Stack Overflow and other sources I have found. To the best of my knowledge the examples used in the Faber book and other sources do not address the use-case posed in this question.  At best I can get the first two loops to parallelize but the inner most loop does not parallelize (Loop not vectorized: data dependency).  As I am looking for general guidance I am not posting the bits that have failed so that a more pedagogical discussion / tips are provided.

Okay, now to my questions.

1. How do I handle the unknown dimensions of the input position arrays using pragma directives?
2. How do I manage the accumulation of the dist[] array (which itself has a length that is unknown at compile time due to the number of pairs of particles)?
3. What pragma directives are generally recommended for this problem?
4. How does one handle the dependency of the "k-loop" on the "j-loop"?
5. Should one flatten the problem to help define the directives to use?

thx,

SB

UPDATE:

To provide results per the suggestion of @jefflarkin I altered the code to account for the indexing of the dist array and added the suggested pragmas. The subroutine compiles fine and runs in parallel.  I will now start profiling to see how to optimize the routine to maximize resource utilization. Here is a copy of the working code:

```
#pragma acc data copyin(position[nsteps][nparticles][3]) copy(dist[npairs])
for(i=0 ; i < nsteps ; i++){
    #pragma acc parallel loop
    for(j=0 ; j < nparticles-1 ; j++){
        x1 = position[i][j][0] ;
        y1 = position[i][j][1] ;
        z1 = position[i][j][2] ;
        #pragma acc loop
        for(k=j+1 ; k < nparticles ; k++){
            x2 = position[i][k][0] ;
            y2 = position[i][k][1] ;
            z2 = position[i][k][2] ;
            dx2 = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) ;
            dy2 = (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) ;
            dz2 = (z1 - z2) * (z1 - z2) ;
            sdist = sqrt(dx2 + dy2 + dz2) ;
            local_count = ((j*nparticles)-((j*(j+1))/2))+k-(j+1) ;
            dist[local_count] += sdist ;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this compiler result (pgc++ (16.10): CFLAGS= -fPIC -c -fast -acc -Minfo=accel -ta=multicore -O3 -shared)

```
 38, Generating Multicore code
 39, #pragma acc loop gang
 45, Loop is parallelizable
```

and for GPU (CFLAGS= -v -fPIC -c -fast -acc -Minfo=accel -ta=tesla:cuda8,fastmath -O3 -shared)

```
 35, Generating copyin(coor[:nframes][:nparticles][:3])
     Generating copy(dist[:npairs])
 38, Accelerator kernel generated
     Generating Tesla code
     39, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */
     45, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
 45, Loop is parallelizable
```

where line 35 i-loop (nsteps), line 38 is the j-loop and line 45 is the k-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the size of the arrays is unknown, but you can calculate them for your data clauses based on nparticles. The position array is size [nparticles][nparticles][3]. The dist array is a little trickier, because k shrinks for each j, but it's the sum of (nparticles - 1) + (nparticles - 2) + ... + 1, which I believe is (nparticles * (nparticles - 1))/2. Even though the number of particles may not be determined until runtime, the compiler must know something about the array otherwise the [] wouldn't work.

I'd suggest changing the indexing into the dist array so that you can calculate the the index into that array based on j and k, otherwise you'll need an atomic operation to protect the increment of pair and that wouldn't guarantee that for each step the same pair of points will be at the same place in the distance array.

With that fixed, I'd think a `acc data` on the steps loop, `acc parallel loop` on the j loop, and a simple `acc loop` on the k loop (to help the compiler out with dependency analysis) ought to get you up and running.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Now onto learning more about openacc.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. If the current troubles are resolved, would you mind please marking the answer as accepted so that others will see it as resolved if they face similar problems in the future?